# What indexes should I add to cover most cases?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table of multiple choice test answers:

```
Table Answers (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT,
    StudyId INT, -- each study is a set of questions
    PracticeId INT, -- each practice run (user may respond to a test multiple times)
    QuestionId INT, 
    Valid BIT
)
```

The table will be large (millions of rows), and I will be running all sorts of stats on it. For example:

1. For a user in a study show 5 worst performing questions (which was answered incorrectly most times across all practice runs)

   select top 5 questionid, 100*sum(valid)/count(*) rate from answer where
   userid=xxx and studyid=xxx group by questionid order by rate
2. Show 5 most difficult questions (worst response rate) in a study across all users:

   select top 5 questionid, 100*sum(valid)/count(*) rate from answer
   where studyid=xxx group by questionid order by rate

etc.

I can't foresee all possible types of stats I will be gathering. I would still like to set some generic indexes upfront. But, it looks like I would need to create indexes for various combinations of fields and I am not sure how to approach it best when I don't know the full scope of statistical queries.

Any ideas how to approach it "the right way"?

Comment: Don't get stuck doing premature optimization. Create your database as you know it to be right now. As the system matures you can add any additional indexes as you need them.

Comment: You'll need to answer a few questions about the table to make those decisions - there is not going to be a good answer to this question.  How often are you performing DML on this table and how many records per operation?  Which field(s) are going to provide you with the best selectivity?  Will you be using any kind of partitioning or partitioned views?  How is your data spread across key values - balanced, skewed, shifting? Answer these and start with your clustering key and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by putting a single column non clustered index on each of the foreign keys. This should be standard practice for all foreign keys that you create, unless you have a specific reason not to. Using index intersections, http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2013/02/14/index-intersection.aspx , most of the queries will at least be able to filter down the rows.

Creating an index on the bit column probably won't be useful because I'm assuming it won't be selective enough for either value.

You have all of these columns using the default of allowing nulls. I'm assuming that you're actually planning on making them non nullable? If not, and you're planning on leaving some of them as nullable, you could look into sparse columns and filtered indexes, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx .

Your possible composite and covering indexes are the ones that you're going to have to wait and see what the most common heavy queries are to tune for.

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 columns which are apparently foreign keys. Build an index for each column of those for the sake of FK performance. This will be a good enough start for query performance tuning. There is no need to stuck on it right now - there is no rocket science in queries you mentioned and table structure is absolutely ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create the indexes you might need up front I suggest that you populate the table and try out some queries.  Then, when you know what queries will be run frequently you can run though queries through the SQL Server Tuning Adviser which will suggest indexes and stats for you.

Guessing up front will probably just create indexes that you don't need and won't use.